# mysql left join takes too long

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

I have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    upd.*,
    usr.username AS `username`,
    usr.profile_picture AS `profile_picture`
FROM 
    updates AS upd
LEFT JOIN 
    subscribers AS sub ON upd.uid=sub.suid
LEFT JOIN 
    users AS usr ON upd.uid=usr.uid
WHERE 
    upd.deleted='0' && (upd.uid='118697835834' || sub.uid='118697835834')
GROUP BY upd.id
ORDER BY upd.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 15
```

where i get all user(118697835834) updates, his profile picture from another table using left join and also all his subscription users updates so can i show them in his newsfeed.

However as the updates get more and more so the query takes more time to load... right now using Codeigniter's Profiler i can see that the query takes **1.3793**...

Right now i have created around 18k dummy accounts and subscribed from to me and vice versa so i can test the execution time... the times that i get are tragic considering that i am in localhost...

I also have some indexes where i suppose need more in the users table(username and uid as unique), updates table(update_id as unique and uid as index)

I suppose i am doing something wrong to get so bad results...

**EDIT**:
Running EXPLAIN EXTENDED result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => SIMPLE
            [table] => upd
            [type] => ALL
            [possible_keys] => i2
            [key] => 
            [key_len] => 
            [ref] => 
            [rows] => 22
            [filtered] => 100.00
            [Extra] => Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => SIMPLE
            [table] => sub
            [type] => ALL
            [possible_keys] => 
            [key] => 
            [key_len] => 
            [ref] => 
            [rows] => 18244
            [filtered] => 100.00
            [Extra] => Using where
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [select_type] => SIMPLE
            [table] => usr
            [type] => eq_ref
            [possible_keys] => uid
            [key] => uid
            [key_len] => 8
            [ref] => site.upd.uid
            [rows] => 1
            [filtered] => 100.00
            [Extra] => 
        )

)
```

**EDIT2: SHOW CREATE of Tables**
Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 `password` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 `profile_picture_full` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `profile_picture` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `date_registered` datetime NOT NULL,
 `activated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `closed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=23521 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Subscribers table:

```
CREATE TABLE `subscribers` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `suid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=18255 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Updates table:

```
CREATE TABLE `updates` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `update_id` bigint(19) NOT NULL,
 `uid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `type` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `update` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `total_likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `total_comments` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `total_favorites` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `category` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `deleted_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `i1` (`update_id`),
 KEY `i2` (`uid`),
 KEY `deleted_index` (`deleted`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Use EXPLAIN so that you can see how the query is being executed

Comment: have you done `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` (prepend it to your query)

Comment: did you index everything that are you searching and joining?

Comment: I also have some indexes where i suppose need more in the users table(username and uid as unique), updates table(update_id as unique and uid as index)

Comment: Index that puppy before worrying about anything else. Today I got a 120 second query down to .05 seconds from indexing. Also you seem to be treating uids as a string in the SQL?

Comment: Why are you storing everything as string? And what purpose does `GROUP BY` serve?

Comment: Could you please add the table definitions (the results of `SHOW CREATE tablename` for all three tables). Can there be more than one entry for each (userid,updateid) combination (I don't understand the `GROUP BY upd.id` in the query)?

Comment: `Using temporary; Using filesort` - that's amongst the worst things that can happen to a query; but at least `full table scan, temporary, filesort` would be worse, there's hope ;-)

Comment: @Naltharial, if i remove it the query will show one update again and again...

Comment: @VolkerK i have added all of 3 tables the SHOW CREATE of them

Comment: @VolkerK Considering `[type] => ALL`, I'm not sure it's far off. That `WHERE` is probably run on a full table scan instead of an index. Really, 75% of performance issues is solved by indexes and 20% by people avoiding `JOIN`s for some far-fetched reason.

Comment: @Naltharial as i see the 3rd table has [type] => eq_ref ... so you mean that the other tables dont use the INDEXes ?

Comment: @fxuser `eq_ref` is only used by `Users`, beacuse it's a one-to-one ID mapping. Do you have indexes on `upd.uid` and `sub.suid`?

Comment: @Naltharial yes i have on these too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one (without the `GROUP BY`):

```
SELECT 
    upd.*,
    usr.username AS `username`,
    usr.profile_picture AS `profile_picture`
FROM 
        updates AS upd
    LEFT JOIN 
        users AS usr 
            ON  upd.uid = usr.uid
WHERE 
    upd.deleted='0' 
  AND 
    ( upd.uid='118697835834'
   OR EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM   subscribers AS sub 
        WHERE  upd.uid = sub.suid
          AND  sub.uid = '118697835834'
      )
    )
ORDER BY upd.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 15
```

---

At least the columns that are used in Joins should be indexed: `updates.uid`, `users.uid` and `subscribers.suid`.

I would also add an index on `subscribers.uid`.

Comment: this is indeed hella faster... i now need to index properly to hopefully get better performance

Comment: @fxuser: Edit your question and add the descriptions of your tables (column datatypes, indexes and PK, FKs).

Comment: users.uid is indexed as unique, updates.uid is indexed as index and subscribers.uid and suid are indexed as index aswell

Comment: Index(uid, suid) or Index(suid, uid)? You may need the other one, depending on what the `EXPLAIN` for this query tells you. I'd also still remove the quotes, if they're not necessary.

Comment: @Naltharial if you are talking about the subscribers table i have 2 separate indexes with uid and suid respectively... do i have to add another column with them(id) ? - about the quotes i am seeing that it gives performance and im going to remove them where necessary

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT 
    upd.*,
    usr.username AS `username`,
    usr.profile_picture AS `profile_picture`
FROM 
    updates AS upd
LEFT JOIN 
    subscribers AS sub ON upd.uid=sub.suid
LEFT JOIN 
    users AS usr ON upd.uid=usr.uid
WHERE 
    upd.deleted=0 and upd.uid in (118697835834,118697835834)
GROUP BY upd.id
ORDER BY upd.date DESC
LIMIT 0, 15
```

Note that `'` has been removed from numeric values and bitwise operators changed to conventional operators.

Answer (score 1):

don't use joins, try this one:

```
select  *, 
        (select username from users where uid = upd.uid) as username,
        (select profile_picture from users where uid = upd.uid) as profile_picture,
from    updates as upd
WHERE 
    upd.deleted='0' && upd.uid='118697835834'
```

(not tested!)

maybe you have to check if there exists a subscriber in the where-clause with another sub-select.

Another way would be to make a join on sub-selects and not on the whole table. This may increase your performance also.

Comment: And the rationale for avoiding `JOIN`s is? Can you post an `EXPLAIN` plan from your query that is better than the `JOIN`ed one?

Comment: @Naltharial: I have not set up the database, so I have no EXPLAIN. But I have often increased performace by avoiding 'joins' in my projects.

Comment: @fxuser: subscribers have to be checked by an EXISTS (as I mentioned in my comment and as you did in your example)

Comment: That's because MySQL will implicitly convert your sub-selects into appropriate `JOIN`s where it can. `JOIN`s are almost always better for performance (unless you can provide hard data where your usage differs from the norm), because the engine can optimize them far more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't take too long to run; do you have an index on 'deleted'?  What is the 'GROUP BY id' doing? Should it be UID? Can it come out, if ID is in fact just an auto increment, unique ID? (which would be expensive as well as pointless)

Comment: added an index on deleted, nothing changed. GROUP BY id is required for the query to show all updates that i get because by removing it it will keep showing 1 again and again..

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be best separating this query into a select on the user table and then union those results with the select on the subscribers table.

Comment: Also start with the users table and then joint the updates onto that. It's likely that your update table will be much larger that your users.